# How to define the recurrence formula for pyramid of spheres game using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have this problem:

*Given a pyramid of spheres like the shown above, where each sphere has an associated number (positive or negative) which represents its score. The player can choose any of the spheres inside of the pyramid and the general score will be computed from the the sphere(s) immediately above it.*

*What is the maximum score who a player can obtain?*

*This is an example of a pyramid of N=6*

[image: Pyramid of level 6]

*Game illustration:*

- *If the player chooses the sphere at the top of the pyramid, the total score is: 13.*
- *If the player chooses the third sphere at level 3 (value: 11), the spheres of level 2 with number 54 and 9 must also be removed. The previous two spheres require that the two spheres of level 1 must also be removed, because they are above of the sphere with 54, and above of the sphere with 9. And finally, the sphere with 13 value must be removed. Total score: 13 + 32 - 7 + 54 + 9 + 11 = 112.*

Requirements:

1. Determine the total score when an sphere is chosen from the pyramid.
2. Determine the maximum score which is possible to achieve among all the spheres.

The requirement number 1 must be solved using dynamic programming.

**Solution:**

First, this is the notation/language for the problem:

Each sphere is denoted with the tuple `(i,j)`; where `i` represents the level (`0<=i<=n`), and `j` is the location of the sphere from left to right.

`v(i,j)`: value of the sphere at `(i,j)`, `0<=j<=i<=N`.

`p(i,j)` = "total score when the player chooses the sphere `(i,j)`", `1<=i<=N`.

Recurrences:

This is what I have done to define the recurrence formulas:

`p(i,j)=v(0,0)`, if `i=0`

`= v(i-1, j-1) + v(i-1, j+1)`, if `i>0 &  0 <= j < i + 1`

As you see, I'm experimenting some difficulties to specify the recurrence formulas to compute the score for given chosen sphere.

Some ideas or suggestions to define it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like if we try to calculate current p(i,j) by summarizing current value with previous level p(i-1, j-1) and p(i-1,j) then p(i-2, j-1) calculated twice for left branch p(i-1, j-1) and right one. To fix it, we can subtract one p(i-2, j-1) from the result:

```
p(i,j) = v(i,j) + p(i-1, j-1) + p(i-1, j) - p(i-2, j-1)
```

Comment: which data structure you recommend to store the previous/partial computed results for this problem?

Comment: I think this data structure is the same as you using to store pyramid values - some kind of 2-dimensional array

Comment: Thanks. What I want to know is what is the best way to store previous computed values, i.e., the results of the above spheres.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

`p(i == 0, j == 0) = v(0,0)`

`p(i,j) = p(i-1, j-1) + p(i-1, j) + v(i,j), if i>0 &  0 <= j < i + 1, otherwise 0`

This is because the one to the upper left is `j-1`, and the one to the upper right is `j`, and we also need to add the spheres value too. Looks like you used `v` instead of `p` for the upper left and right, but we need to continue up and recursively compute the value until we reach the `i>0 &  0 <= j < i + 1` or `0,0` condition

(sorry for the badly written answer, need to sleep soon so edits are welcome)